# Laravel Eloquent - Query with multiples parameters

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm new to the Laravel framework and I could need a little help from you.

Could someone help me to convert this request into Eloquent ?

```
SELECT * FROM `non_working_days` WHERE YEAR(date) = "2021" AND (country = "Paris" OR country = "Madrid")
```

For the moment I have managed to find a solution but I am running as many queries as the number of parameters.

```
foreach ($calendar as $code) {
  array_push(
    $data,
    Model::query()
      ->whereYear('date', '=', $year)
      ->where('country', $code)
      ->get()
  );
}
```

So it comes down to doing :

```
SELECT * FROM `non_working_days` WHERE YEAR(date) = "2021" AND country = "Paris"
SELECT * FROM `non_working_days` WHERE YEAR(date) = "2021" AND country = "Madrid"
```

So I don't think it's very efficient knowing that potentially I would have many more parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) method:

```php
$countries = ['Paris', 'Madrid']; // or use $calendar instead if it's an array
$data = Model::query()
    ->whereYear('date', '=', $year)
    ->whereIn('country', $countries)
    ->get();
```

This should give you a query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `non_working_days` WHERE YEAR(`date`) = "2021" AND `country` IN ("Paris", "Madrid");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, by

```
Model::query()
       ->whereYear('date', '=', $year) 
       ->where( function( $whereQry ) use( $country_1, $country_2 ) {
            $whereQry->orWhere( 'country', $country_1 );
            $whereQry->orWhere( 'country', $country_2 );
       })
       ->get();
```

its convert into exactly what you need,

```
SELECT * FROM `non_working_days` WHERE YEAR(date) = "2021" AND (country = "Paris" OR country = "Madrid")
```

Comment: Your proposal seems correct to me only if I only have two parameters. As soon as I have several parameters the code will be very complicated. I think it is better to use OR key IN ('key1', 'key2'). Thank you for your help.

Comment: `whereIn` is the best if you want to match multi-value to a single column. But this one will help you where you actually need the `OR` operation in your SQL query. So this is for your future use.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using where in and you dont need to make loop for this,like this :-

```
Model::query()
  ->whereYear('date', '=', $year)
  ->whereIn('country', $calendar)
  ->get()
```

Comment: but $countries array should be like this :- ['Paris', 'Madrid']